# Unpredictable Behaviour handlebars helper reverse for loop

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I created this helper function for a handlebars template

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('reverse_for', function(from, to, decrease, block) {
    var result = '';
    for(var i = from; i >= to; i -= decrease)
        result += block.fn(i);
    return result;
});
```

The code seems to work irradical. It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't return the value of {{ this }} (in handlebars.js template) although it has the correct inputs and loops over the correct number of items.

This is how I output it in a handlebars.js template

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Bar Width {{baseComponents.bar.product.max_width}} - {{baseComponents.bar.product.min_width}}</label>
    <select class="form-control csb-bar-width-selector">
        {{#reverse_for baseComponents.bar.product.max_width baseComponents.bar.product.min_width 1}}
            <option value="{{this}}">{{this}} inches</option>
        {{/reverse_for}}
    </select>
</div>
```

Again it sometimes works. Here is an example of it working on the first time around but not the second time. When I reload it might work fully or not at all.

[image]

Again sometimes {{ this }} outputs the values correct and sometimes it doesn't. I think the problem is in the helper function and how I build the result. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('reverse_for', function(from, to, decrease, options) {
    var result = String('');
    for(var i = parseInt(from); i >= parseInt(to); i -= parseInt(decrease))
    {
        result += String(options.fn({'index':parseInt(i)}));
    }
    return result;
});
```

doesn't seem to have the problem.

In the templates I do now use

```
{{ index }}
```

and not

```
{{ this }}
```

To output the value

The parseInt and String casting didn't seem to affect the irradical results but returning it as an object with only the index key seems not to have this strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
      Handlebars.registerHelper('each_reverse',function (context, options) {
      var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse;
      var length = 0, ret = "", data;

      if (Handlebars.Utils.isFunction(context)) { context = context.call(this); }

      if (options.data) {
        data = Handlebars.createFrame(options.data);
      }

      if(context && typeof context === 'object') {
        if (Handlebars.Utils.isArray(context)) {
            length=context.length;
          for(var j = context.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {//no i18n
            if (data) {
              data.index = j;
              data.first = (j === 0);
              data.last  = (j === (context.length-1));
            }
            ret = ret + fn(context[j], { data: data });
          }
        } else {
                var keys = Object.keys(context);
                length=keys.length;
                for(j=length; j>=0;j--)
                {
                    var key = keys[j-1]
                    if(context.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if(data) { 
                            data.key = key; 
                            data.value = context[key];
                            data.index = j;
                            data.first = (j === 0);
                          }
                          ret += fn(context[key], {data: data});
                    }
                }
        }
      }

      if(length === 0){
        ret = inverse(this);
      }

      return ret;
    } );
```